# react-native network request failed

Tags: networking, react-native

I went through ("all") posts on SO for this issue, but none works for me. The request url works on browsers (Safari, FF, Chrome, IE), it also works when I run the app through Xcode. But when i run the app through

```
react-native run-iso
react-native run-android
```

I am running: **react-native-cli: 2.0.1, react-native: 0.41.2, Xcode: 8.2.1**

they both failed

[image]

The URL i am using has no certificate error, and I have the following setting for iOS.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Someone said downgrading react-native have fixed this issue. I haven't tried that yet. Please let me know what else i can do.

Thanks.

**EDITTED:**
I have the ATS setting, please see the original post content. **And this is happening on both iOS and Android. The app only works when i build and run from Xcode**

this is the code i am running in one of my component:

```
componentDidMount: function()  {

  this.fetchData();
},
fetchData: function()  {
   var url = "https://company_rest_api.com/categories"

   fetch(url,
     {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    console.log(responseJson)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  }).done();
 }
```

Comment: Can you please show some code? What kind of URL are you trying to talk to, using what protocol?

Comment: Also see https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48979 if that's the reason for your problem, downgrading RN is unlikely to do the trick

Comment: You basically just have to allow arbitrary loads on your info.plist - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8118

Comment: edited my post, please let me know what you think. thanks.

Comment: I have the Allow Arbitrary Loads setting for iOS. But this is happening on both iOS and Android.

Comment: Hi @triston, have you found the solution for this?